# void org.openqa.selenium.WebElement.click() Note: This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found

Tags: selenium

I wrote the below code :

```
package LoginMercuryTour;

import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
public class LoginMercuryTour {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        String baseUrl="http://newtours.demoaut.com/";
        driver.get(baseUrl);
        WebElement userName;
        WebElement Password;
        userName=driver.findElement(By.name("userName"));
        Password=driver.findElement(By.name("password"));
        userName.sendKeys("tutorial");
        Password.sendKeys("tutorial");
        driver.findElement(By.name("login")).click();
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value='oneway']")).click();
        Select passengersCnt=new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("passCount")));
        passengersCnt.selectByVisibleText("1");
        Select Dep=new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("fromPort")));
        Dep.selectByVisibleText("London");      
    }
}
```

this is ruuning fine without any error. But the click functionality is not working. the button is not getting clicked. While checking the javadoc it is showing 
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.FirefoxDriver()
Note: This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found.

Note: I am able to click the Login button.
But the second click is not working/

Please Help. I am a beginner to selenium Webdriver.

Comment: What is your html code?

Answer (score 0):

It's working just fine for me. The `Thread.sleep()` is not needed so I commented it out. I simplified a few things in your code but other than that, it's all the same. The sleep was 10s so maybe you didn't give it time to finish?

If you aren't going to reuse the `username` and `password` elements, there is no need to store them in variables so I removed the declaration and combine the `sendKeys()` call with the find. I changed the passenger count to 4 to make sure that part was working since the default is 1.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
String baseUrl = "http://newtours.demoaut.com/";
driver.get(baseUrl);
driver.findElement(By.name("userName")).sendKeys("tutorial");
driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("tutorial");
driver.findElement(By.name("login")).click();
// Thread.sleep(10000);
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value='oneway']")).click();
Select passengersCnt = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("passCount")));
passengersCnt.selectByVisibleText("4");
Select Dep = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("fromPort")));
Dep.selectByVisibleText("London");
```

If you want to fix the no Javadoc error, mk08 provided that solution.

Answer (score -1):

As selenium is distributed in form of JARs, you need to add explicitly a java doc location for it. Follow the instruction given in [THIS blog](http://www.silverwareconsulting.com/index.cfm/2010/5/17/Getting-Started-with-WebDriver-a-Browser-Automation-Tool) (9th & 10th instruction). It should resolve the problem.